# should I create a hapijs plugin or use server.ext to screen for an api-key in the header

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

So I'd like to check all http routes to my hapi rest api for a valid api key.  I don't want to use an auth plugin as I will also have basic auth on some routes in addition to the api token check.  I'm used to doing this as middleware in express, but what's the right way in hapi?

Should I create my own plugin or instead use server.ext to accomplish this.. or should I do it  yet another way?

So far this is the way I've done it

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, next) {

    //make sure its https
    if(request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] && request.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === "http") {
        return next(Boom.badRequest('ssl is required'));
    }
    else
    {
        if (request.headers['x-api-key'] != apiToken) {
            return next(Boom.unauthorized('api key is incorrect'));
        }
        else
        {
            next();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would use an auth plugin. You can use multiple authentication strategies at the same time.

Comment: how do you set a route to use more than one auth strategy, do you just pass an array of strings into the auth property?  I tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Added an example as an answer. Basically you need to use the `strategies` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an authentication plugin. You can use multiple authentication strategies at the same time, you are not limited to one. Here is an example how to do it:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server(3000);

server.pack.register([require('hapi-auth-basic'), require('hapi-auth-cookie')], function(err) {

  server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { ... });
  server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', { ... });

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    auth: {
      strategies: ['simple', 'session']
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      reply('success');
    }
  });

  server.start(function() {
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
  });

});
```

See [Authentication](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth) for more details:

> When specifying one strategy, you may set the `strategy` property to a
>   string with the name of the strategy. When specifying more than one
>   strategy, the parameter name must be `strategies`and should be an
>   array of strings each naming a strategy to try. The strategies will
>   then be attempted in order until one succeeds, or they have all
>   failed.

Comment: can you make it so that all must succeed rather than just having it pass if only one succeeds? E.g. api auth key must always be true, and some routes will also need to be user authenticated as well.

Comment: I think that would be possible only with a custom code that you have tried to write. Ideally you shouldn't make two strategies required. An API token should identify and authenticate the user, same with basic authentication. So it should be enough if one strategy succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

While Gergo's reponse is good, I have a similar use case where I also need strategies to behave in such a way that:

```
A (Succeed) --> B (Succeed) --> Handler

A (Fail) --> reply(4xx) || A(succeed) --> B (fail) --> reply(4xx)
```

I handled it in this way

```
server.ext('onPostAuth', function(request, reply) {
  request.server.auth.test('A', request, function(err) {
    return err ? reply(err) : reply.continue();
  });
});

server.ext('onPostAuth', function(request, reply) {
  request.server.auth.test('B', request, function(err) {
    return err ? reply(err) : reply.continue();
  });
});
```